# How to select the checkbox based on the Text

Tags: robotframework

How to check the checkbox based on the Text value.

**1**. Text Value is dynamic and is separated from check box.

**2**. I need to check the checkbox only if that text is present.

Here is the HTML code:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="_Adjustment3" headerid="226849" detailid="380105" onchange="enableDisableAmountBox(this)" class="ace" xpath="1">
    <span class="lbl" xpath="1">
        <a href="#"/>
    </span>
</td>
<td xpath="1">AutomatedSchedule$03/04/2019, $, $, $, $</td>
<td xpath="1">10000</td>
```

I want to check the check box based on text (i.e., AutomatedSchedule$03/04/2019, $, $, $, $)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Presume the text `AutomatedSchedule` is constant and rest of the text is getting change.

In that case use contains and look for sub-string in side td tag.

1. identify the `td` tag with text contains `AutomatedSchedule`.
2. then use `preceding-sibling` td which contains `input` `checkbox`.
3. use Wait Until Element Is Visible.
4. Then click on the element.

```
Wait Until Element Is Visible   xpath://td[contains(.,'AutomatedSchedule')]/preceding-sibling::td[1]/input[@type='checkbox']      10

Click Element    xpath://td[contains(.,'AutomatedSchedule')]/preceding-sibling::td[1]/input[@type='checkbox']
```